# How to untar an archive without the root folder, but keeping the full hierarchy inside it?

Tags: command-line, tar

If I’ve got a `.tar` archive, and when I extract it, it gives me a single folder `foo` containing some more stuff, like this:

```
foo/
  something.txt
  another.txt
  bar/
    something-else.txt
```

Is there a way I can modify the `.tar` command to “skip” the root folder (`foo` in this case) and just extract all the contents of that folder directly into my cwd like this:

```
something.txt
another.txt
bar/
  something-else.txt
```

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Easy. Just use `--strip-components=1` on the archive like this:

```
tar -xf archive.tar --strip-components=1
```

And as explained in the official [`tar`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tar) man page:

> --strip-components=NUMBER
>
> strip NUMBER leading components from file names on extraction

With the logic being that if a path consists of `foo/something.txt` then the first “component” of that path would be `foo/` so `--strip-components=1` would effectively drop the `foo/` from the path `foo/something.txt`.

Comment: I'd advise only using this for tar files that you know the structure of. Note that `--strip-components` will not just strip leading directories, if you had a tar file that *didn't* have a directory as its top level entry (e.g., if the contents of the tar file were [file1.txt, somedirectory/] this command would not extract file1.txt. I haven't found a method that only strips a top level *directory* without causing problems with other kinds of tar files that just have plain files as their top level entry.

Comment: Wouldn't have thought tar would work with zip files, but it did.